# I need Information about AA5 qA SOT-23

Tags: sot23

I need Information about "AA5qA" SOT-23 SMD component. I need infos to reverse engineering to find a missing component (blue cycle)
[image]

This is a valve for vehicle and someone try to take-of epoxy and he scratch PCB.

Comment: An objective of this website is that people should be able to fully understand a question by reading the question, without reading all the comments. Comments are intended to be temporary and disposable. That's why I edited your question.

Comment: Seeing that the number is hand written on, I would suspect that it is either a code for a standard component or it is a proprietary component.  What sort of vehicle is it ?